# c++ visual studio 2012 -> 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

At the home I am using visual studio 2012 and when I tried 2010 with my code at school, many things didn't work like `std::to_wstring()` only viable arguments where long double, and at home I am using it to convert an int to a wstring.

My Question is, if I only take my .exe to the school where only 2010 is installed, will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can work.
you can take my.exe and related version `vc_redist.exe` to school installed only 2010.

The Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package (x86) installs runtime components of Visual C++ Libraries required to run applications developed with Visual C++ on a computer that does not have Visual C++ 2012 installed.

Comment: Just curious: will have have to use a release build for this, or will does the redist package now include what you need for debug builds.  (It didn't used to, but I haven't looked for quite some time.)

Comment: You are not permitted (license restriction) to run debug builds without Visual Studio so the redistributable does not contain debug dlls.